# Does anyone know why I get a file not found error in Jenkins when opening a JSON file with Python (Locust)?

Tags: python, rest, jenkins, filenotfoundexception, locust

I'm using Locust for load testing - creating a lot of post requests to a server.
Because I need to generate different fields for every request, The best way to do it in my opinion is to read the body from a file, change the relevant fields and send the request.

The problem occurs when I open the file

I see in the Jenkins log that there is a FileNotFound exception - even though I see the file in the git repo from where the Jenkins runs the code.

I tried putting the full path in the `with` statement but still got the same exception.

```
    ...
    with open('postRequest.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
        data = json.load(jsonFile)

    data["a"] = b
    data["x"] = y
    data[["something"] = something_else
    return json.dumps(data)
```

Jenkins fails opening the file.

**Note : The code works when I don't read the file, but just create a very long JSON string.**

Thanks all !! ;)

Comment: provide the absolute path.

Comment: did it, didn't work

Comment: The file isn't where you think it is?

Comment: Always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: currently it's in the same directory as the locust python file.
I'm trying to figure out the absolute path in jenkins

Comment: @wwii what do you mean

Comment: @raziv Are you running locust from a different folder? If you run "locust -f mydir/locustfile.py" then your current directory is outside mydir, not inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved, in the Jenkins the full path is different than I thought it was.
Anyway, ran pwd and saw where I was - added the path where the file was and worked.

Thanks friends !